# Forecasting with lagged data

Tags: regression, forecasting, panel-data, scikit-learn

I'm trying to forecast some values with information about many variables from the past, there's a description of the data:

It contains information over the time from 5 sensors for different variables ie:

| sensor | var1 | var2 | var3 | target | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sensor1 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| sensor2 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

and so on...
after a transformation data becomes

| sensor | var1 | var2 | var3 | var1(t-1) | var2(t-1) | var3(t-1) | target(t-1) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sensor1 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |  |
| sensor2 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |  |

Until t-8.

However, when forecasting using sklearn linear regressor I see that there's a delay and the model is almost telling that the next value is the previous one. Have you faced this before? what you've done? is this wrong? :( Please help

Thank you!

Comment: what software is this?

Comment: I didn't understand D: I'm using python, pandas and sklearn

Comment: Sorry I know nothing of python, thus my question. I was not really sure what you were asking. I use R and SAS.

Comment: No worries, what I'm having currently is a lag between the actual and forecasted value. I'm using a lag of 15 days for the target variable and other variables and I wanted to knwo if there's something wrong and how to fix it :(.

Comment: You can use lags to predict anything. There are dangers including autocorrelation, non-stationarity, and many other factors which are serious. Since I don't know python how exactly (what method not tool) are you using to predict. There are many types of time series and its hard to answer not knowing which approach you are using. I am not truly an expert in any case, I just read time series.